# PouchDB Update Document: DataCloneError

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, pouchdb

This is the code that I have been working on for a while. For some reason, it is returning me the following error:

```
Uncaught DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': An object could not be cloned.
```

This is happening even before I tried to use upsert plugin.

```
db.get(id).then(doc => {
    console.log(doc);
    return db.upsert(id, doc => {
        doc.exp_date = moment(doc.exp_date).add(parseInt(document.getElementById('ext_date').value), 'years');
        return doc;
    }).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err));
})
```

May I know the resolution for this error?

Answer (score 1):

The Moment instance can't be cloned. Try:

```
postMessage(moment(0), '*'); // also throws DataCloneError DOMException
```

The [logic for cloning](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#structuredserialize) disallows copying functions, which may be the case. Compare with:

```
postMessage({f: function(){}}); // also throws DataCloneError
```

And check:

```
typeof moment(0)._locale.ordinal; // "function"
```

You'll need to convert the object returned by `add()` to something that can be cloned, such as a Date, number, etc.

Comment: I worked around the problem but in a bit different way. I got answer on PouchDB issues. I simply used `moment(...).add(...)._d`